P channel MOSFET for PWM Peltier control (Arduino)
I want to control the power of a Peltier device using a MOSFET PWM controlled by an Arduino.
In order to "smooth" the power going to the Peltier, I want to add a capacitor in parallel.
The "Power rail" is 12 V while the Arduino PWM is 5 V.
I will have, at most 2 A going through the system.
Is such a circuit OK?
Do you have suggestion as to what reference MOSFET to use?
Thanks,
Cyrille


Does this answer your question? Driving a Peltier element with PWM

In addition, your MOSFET will always be on because it's backwards. And if you flipped it around, your gate voltage will still be too low to ever turn it off.

" I will have, at most 2 A going through the system." The schematic provided doesn't show how this 2A current limit is achieved. Perhaps the +12V voltage source is current-limited to 2A? BTW: you might want to swap drain & source on that PMOS, but then you'll  need another transistor to drive its gate from the 5V Arduino.

you have to pull up the gate to 12v, then pull it down with a p-channel or NPN transistor or an open-collector optocoupler driven by your (inverted) PWM signal. you can also use a high-side photovoltaic mosfet driver to place an n-chan there, which often runs cooler.

A P-MOSFET connected as you show it will always be on, regardless of the PWM signal:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The MOSFET is "upside down."  If you turn it right side up, it still won't work properly because the gate voltage has to get up to 12V to turn off the MOSFET.
If you turn it "right side up" and increase the PWM voltage to 12V, then you get what you're after:

simulate this circuit

You'd need an extra transistor to use a P-MOSFET to drive your Peltier element.  The easier way is to use a N-MOSFET:

simulate this circuit

That's using a 5 V PWM signal and a logic level N-MOSFET.
You still have the problem that Peltier elements don't do well on PWM.  You need to either use a larger capacitor or increase the PWM frequency.
Increasing the PWM frequency is cheaper than using a 1000uF or 1mF capacitor.
Here's the same circuit using 10kHz instead of the Arduino standard 540Hz:

simulate this circuit


Hello, Thanks a LOT for this great answer...
I can definitely add some capacitence (I can probably put 2 or 3 100µF in parallel), and increase the PWM...
Can I use a IRF540N instead of the SMT mosfet that you are using?
Thanks,

IRF540N has curves for 5V Vgs but isn't strictly speaking a logic level device. However, given that you have a 12V source and are PWMing the signal, I think that using the Arduino to drive a gate driver which in turn supplies 12V to the MOSFET might be a good setup.
